# How to use Fabric Crashlytics and Google Analytics in framework iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, frameworks, crashlytics

Earlier I had 2 separate iOS app lets say app1 and app2. I wanted to use app2 from app1 so I moved all code from app2 to a framework and integrated it in app1. For using app2 as separately I created app3 and used same app2 framework.
Now everything is fine except I am facing 2 problems.

1. How to integrate Crashlytics in framework.
2. How to integrate Google Analytics in framework.

It is really important as my app3 is totally a framework and also it will be great if could get data from app1 containing framework.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are these iOS apps external to you?

Comment: Hi Mike, I couldn't get what you exactly mean by external. Framework I build is only used in my apps and will not be made public.

Comment: Gotcha, is your framework dynamic or static?

Comment: It's a dynamic framework

Comment: In that case having the links should do the trick. What issues do you see with your current implementation?

Comment: Hi Mike, using this link https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install, I tried to add crashlytics to my app containing my framework. Crashes from framework are not shown properly like line no is not there, its like _TFC17TestPodsFramework20InsideViewController14onDangerActionfP_T_ + 109.

Comment: Also as I am using same framework in multiple application, if it could be possible to get the framework related crashed as separate bundle report, not messing the individual apps report.

Comment: Gotcha, we will probably need more space to chat through this. Can you email support(at)fabric(dot)io with a reference to this thread and include your app package name please?